# MySQL db export log

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a mySQL db shared between several users and I would like to know if when a user exports all the db into a file there is any log of that operation and who did what... I don't want the data 'floating' arround...
Using PHPmyAdmin or any other client.

Comment: I doubt it. As far as the database is concerned, exporting is just a bunch of `SELECT` statements being done by the client.

Comment: The server has no idea what the client is doing with the results.